# ecryptfs mounts as read only

Tags: mount, filesystem, encryption, fstab, ecryptfs

I did the following (http://haridas.in/how-to-put-encrypted-contents-on-cloud-storages.html), and after mounting, the mounted dir is read-only filesystem:

I created two dirs: one to /home/user/dir1 and /home/user/Dropbox/dir2. Then:

```
mount -t ecryptfs /home/user/Dropbox/dir2 /home/user/dir1
```

Selected: aes/16 bytes/plaintext passthrough yes/filename encryption no

Created /root/.ecryptfsrc file with following content:

```
key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/home/user/.ecryptfs/passphrase.txt
ecryptfs_sig=mysighere
ecryptfs_cipher=aes
ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
ecryptfs_passthrough=y
ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n
```

Created file /home/user/.ecryptfs/passphrase.txt with content:

```
passphrase_passwd=mypassphrase
```

Added line to /etc/fstab:

```
/home/user/Dropbox/dir2 /home/user/dir1 ecryptfs defaults 0 0
```

And now the dir2 and dir1 are read only filesystem. What should I do to change them to mount as read-write filesystem? When I add the line to fstab, the filesystem mounts as it should, but when system boots, it's mounted as a read-only filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Check write permissions in your mounts :

- Type `cat /etc/mtab` and find your ecrypt device
- Remount the partition with read/write permissions : `sudo mount -i -o remount,rw /path/to/your/Device/or/.Private`